# What is the relationship between Collection and Stream

Tags: collections, java-8, stream, dependencies, uml

There is `Stream`, which can be retrieved from `Collection`, in **Java 8**, that is `public default stream<E> Collection.stream()`. So I would like to express the relationship between `Stream` and `Collection` with UML for practice.

I think the proper relationship is **dependency**. But I am not sure about it. So I hereto would like to know **what is the proper relationship between `Collection` and `Stream` in the aspect of UML**? If so **what is the tenet of dependency**?

Comment: since `stream` is called via a `default` method it seems you are more looking into how to map that into `UML`, but to me that is a `dependency` indeed - but it's not anything special in this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Collection` of `E` is an aggregate, and it provides a method `stream()` which returns a `Stream` of `E`, which uses the collection [as source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--).

So the relationship is rather complicated:  there is a [`<<create>>`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html#usage) dependency from `Collection` to `Stream`.  But at the same time, there is a potentially navigable [association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) from the `Stream` to the `Collection`, although this is not visible for the outside world. By the way, you could represent both with a [templateable element](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html#templateable-element).

So you could have something like this in theory:

[image]

Note however, that in practice you should omit the association between the stream and the collection, because it is not usable for the outside world.  This makes only sense if you're interested in the inner design of the Java class library.   You'd better put a comment on the `<<create>>` constraint explaining in plain language that the one serves as source for the other.

Comment: THANKS A LOT for your explanation. BTW, some UML tool doesnot have <<create>> dependency but a `return` dependency instead. I think they are the same, aren't they?

Comment: @Rui No that is not the same. A `return` dependency it not one of the known standard stereotypes, so it's meaning is not generally known. If a tool does not support the `Standard Profile` it is not considered to be conforming to UML.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Thanks for your explanation :)